# Android NFC tag ID identify different nfc card type

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I want to use NFC reading in my app, where I read the ID of an NFC card.
I have 2 different NFC cards.
When I read them with my USB NFC reader in my computer, I get a 9 digit number for both cards, which is cool. I can identify the cards based on that number.

Tthe problem occurs, when I want to read them in my app, like this:

```java
                            new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTagDiscovered( final Tag tag ) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            System.out.println(tag.toString());

                                            // I get the ID here to identify the card
                                            String id = Long.toString(Utils.toDec(tag.getId())).trim();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            },
                            1 | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK,
                            options);
```

When I log the `toString()` method of the discovered TAG, I get this for the first card:

```
Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic]
```

And when I read the ID below `String id = Long.toString(Utils.toDec(tag.getId())).trim();` I get the same 9 digit number like in my computer, that's great, it's a unique id for the card.

The second card's `toString()`:

```
Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA]
```

And when I read the tag ID, I get a 17 digit number instead of the 9 digit...
I tried to log everything in the discovered TAG, but I can't find the 9 digit number I can read from that card in my computer via USB reader. So I can't identify this NFC card.

How can I solve this? I want to identify the cards via both USB reader and my app, so the 2 numbers has to be the same, like with the first card...

Thanks!  :)

Comment: What is the make and model of the card with the problem of the longer ID as some cards have multiple length ID's for compatibility reasons.

Comment: No problem, if the second card has longer ID, but when I read  it via USB reader in my computer, I don't get this longer ID, but a shorter 9 digit number... So I don't have the exact same unique id that equals in the USB reader in my PC and in my android app...

Comment: Without knowing the make and model of the card I cannot tell you how to read the short or long versions on both the USB reader and Android phone.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/NXP-MIFARE-DESFire-13-56MHz-ISO14443A/dp/B07PN46HNY

Answer (score 1):

So the UID for this card is a 7byte UID as per the Section 7.4 of it's datasheet https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF3DX2_MF3DHX2_SDS.pdf (and as per the Amazon listing)

So it is not a card that has multiple ID's for compatibility but the standard it is using does allow 4,7,10 byte UID's
See page 19 of standard at http://emutag.com/iso/14443-3.pdf

As Per the ISO 1444-3 standard the larger UID are sent in multiple parts and the datasheet

> According to ISO/IEC 14443-3 during the first anti-collision loop the cascade tag returns a value of 88h and also the first 3 bytes of the UID, UID0 to UID2 and BCC. The second anti-collision loop returns bytes UID3 to UID6 and BCC

The process is explained and the problem is explained in the application note https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10927.pdf

So in the Application note section 3.2

> In some cases, the reader infrastructure might be able to handle Double Size UIDs, but the (background) system can only handle 4-byte UIDs. Or vice versa, the reader infrastructure might not be able to handle Double Size UIDs, but the (background) system needs uniqueness and can handle Double Size UIDs.

So the USB reader and the code to run it might be doing the anti-collision wrong because it cannot handle more than the 4Byte UID it is returning, it might not be responding to the data returned by the card and processing the cascade Tag bit (so it might only be actually return the first 3 bytes of the 7 byte UID.

You don't give details of the USB reader used (Make and Model) or the source code or application that is used to read it, so cannot help to see if it can return the correct size UID.

But the Application Note Append 6 give code to convert a 7 byte UID to 4 Byte UID (unfortunately this is in C not Java, but you should be able to translate it to Java) but the USB reader might be returning the correct 4 byte UID as well, so this might not help.

Also for better diagnostics print the values out as Hex not decimal as that would tell you better what is happening.

**Added**
A way to convert byte Array to printable Hex String https://stackoverflow.com/a/332101/2373819

Also if you provide more info with actual UID values from a card, it might be possible to see how the USB reader is going wrong (i.e is the first byte of the UID 88h?)

**Update Note**
Other card is easy to see it is a Mifare Classic which newer versions like the EV1 also has a 7 Byte UID (Very old models had a 4 byte UID) so also should show the bigger decimal UID (If a modern card like the EV1 version) BUT this has also has a 4 Byte UID as the first 4 bytes of the 7 bytes to be compatible with the older versions.

Because you are reading the UID using the generic Tag Technology type it might be truncating this to 4 bytes or it might be an old version. Try getting the Tag in the right specific class before using `getID` e.g.

```java
MifareClassic mMifareClassic = MifareClassic.get(tag);
byte[] uid = mMifareClassic.getID();
```

You could use switch `tag.getTechList();`  to use the correct Tag Technology class for each type of Tag

or Try reading `Block 0` to get the UID directly.

**Summary**
The problem is what USB reader giving as what seems are a 4 byte UID when the card only has a 7 byte UID for the NXP Mifare Desfire card.

On the MifareClassic card it should be the first 4 bytes of the 7 byte UID because this has been newer 7 byte UID cards are designed to be compatible with old 4 byte UID cards and thus you can take a slice of the array to make them match.

On the NXP Mifare Desfire card is it

A) the 4 bytes from the first anti-collision command? (which would include the cascade Tag 88h value)

B) the first 4 bytes of the 7 byte UID? so again you could take a slice to make them match.

Note
Some representation of these values gives the most significant bit first instead of the least significant bit.

For example from your comments one of the long UID's is `36125410196403972` in decimal which is is `8057DE821F3704` in hex but the datasheet says the least significant byte should be 04 identifying NXP as the manufacturer but as you can see from 8057DE821F37`04` is reversed as the most significant bit is first and least significant is last.

So you could try and experimenting with combinations of just taking the first 4 bytes with and without reversing to see if you can get them all to match.

Or get the USB reader to read the correct full 7 byte UID for both the cards (as just using 4 bytes won't guarantee uniqueness (even 7 bytes UID or any size UID should never be used for uniqueness and security because they are too easily faked))

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  :)
When I read the card via USB reader in my PC, i get this: 2183ö8378ö
On android after converting the getId() to decimal, I get this: 36125410196403972
But the raw tag.getId() is this: [B@72e0c8f

Also I tried logging like this, but there is no `getId()` method in `NfcA` or `IsoDep` or `MirafeClassic`.
How can I read `Block0` when there is no `MifareClassic`?

Comment: It' interesting, when I log the techList, there is no MifareClassic..
`android.nfc.tech.IsoDep
android.nfc.tech.NfcA`

The first card has `MifaceClassic`, and it works fine via android and usb reader.
The other card has no `MifareClassic`, only `IsoDep` and `NfcA`. I dont care how many characters the Id is, but I want to get the same id when reading in android or usb reader in my computer.

Comment: These 2 cards look like 2 different makes and models and thus conform to different standards and thus behave differently. I've added how to better convert a byte array to printable hex string

Comment: So the `IsoDep` card does not have the equivalent of Block 0 on the `MifareClassic` as it structure and how it stores data is fundamentally different. Another issue in comparing these values is byte ordering direction e.g. `36125410196403972` is `8057DE821F3704` in hex but the datasheet says the least significant byte should be `04` identifying NXP as the manufacturer but as you can see from 8057DE821F37`04` is reversed as the most significant bit.