# not getting exact result when converting byte array to hex in java

Tags: java, arrays, hex, bytebuffer

I'm trying to get hex string value from bytebuffer using below code. Reference: [In Java, how do I convert a byte array to a string of hex digits while keeping leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l)

```
    public ByteBuffer convert(ByteBuffer in) {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    for (int iter = 0; iter < in.array().length; iter++) {
      byte high = (byte) ( (in.array()[iter] & 0xf0) >> 4);
      byte low =  (byte)   (in.array()[iter] & 0x0f);
      out.append(nibble2char(low));
      out.append(nibble2char(high));
    }
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(out.reverse().toString().getBytes());
   }
   private static char nibble2char(byte b) {
   byte nibble = (byte) (b & 0x0f);
   if (nibble < 10) {
     return (char) ('0' + nibble);
   }
   return (char) ('a' + nibble - 10);
  }
```

The value I got as **701000000000**, Actually I'm expecting a value like this **000000000107**. So I called a reverse method on stringbuffer object at the time of wrapping.

After this I'm always getting "ffffff000000"
Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/10934377) answer.

Comment: @HeikoRibberink I tried it, but getting the result as '070100000000'

Comment: char[] hexChars = new char[in.array().length * 2];
    for (int j = in.array().length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        int v = in.array()[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    out.append(new String(hexChars));

Comment: You could loop over it in reverse order, by changing the for-loop.

Comment: Like this: 
```for (int j = bytes.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {  
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;  
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];  
        hexChars[j * 2 - 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];  
}```
Haven't tested it, but I think it'll work.

Comment: Sorry for the hopeless formatting btw, I thought code blocks would work in comments, but they obviously don't.